# What encoding it is? Gained from [AVMetadataItem value]

Tags: macos, character-encoding

I retrieve a meta info of a mp3 file using AVMetadataItem, and use NSLog to print out the [item value], The output is:

Line 1:  1997-2007 ¿çÊÀ¼Í¹úÓï¾«Ñ¡ CD1
Line 2:  ³ÂÞÈÑ¸
Line 3:  ºÃ¾Ã²»¼û

I know it's Chinese， but I cannot find what encoding it is.
And I also know its corresponding character in Chinese:

Line 1:  1997-2007 跨世纪国语精选 CD1
Line 2:  陈奕迅
Line 3:  好久不见

iTunes recognized the Chinese successfully, so i'm sure there is a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character Encodings - Unicode - CJK Unified Ideographs

```
Block Name: CJK Unified Ideographs
First Code Point: 4E00
Last Code Point: 9FFF
```

http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U4E00.pdf

[http://unicode.org/CJK_Unified_Ideographs](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3aBlock=CJK_Unified_Ideographs%3a%5D)

Comment: Thanks, Can you plz tell me how to find out the encoding?

Comment: @kilik52, sure — all you need to do is copy one of the characters into Character Viewer and it identifies it. From there you can copy/paste the unicode name into google and it will tell you which Block Family and Encoding it's associated with.